# MySQL - Create a Covering Index where the Sorting Option Columns are Identical to the Select Payload Columns

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, mariadb, index-tuning

Something to note up front, I am using Magento 2 so if the query looks a little strange, that's why.

I have the following query and am trying to optimize the indexes for the table;

```
SELECT `main_table`.`id`, 
       `main_table`.`id`, 
       `main_table`.`created_at` 
FROM `yotpo_order_status_history` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (`order_id` = 12709301) 
AND (`store_id` = 1) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'm not sure whether my alter query should include created_at and id only once, as such;

```
alter table yotpo_order_status_history add index (order_id, store_id, created_at, id);
```

Or if I should include them twice like so;

```
alter table yotpo_order_status_history add index (order_id, store_id, created_at, id, created_at, id);
```

I've looked for an answer to this question, but didn't find anything that even mentions this specific scenario. Should I go with the first option without defining the columns twice or do I need to use the second option? I'm familiar with redundant indexes and their performance implications but that's not quite what I've come across here.

Comment: The first. `EXPLAIN` output should confirm

Comment: I thought so, but I wasn't sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is the winner of the two.
But it's not the best. The best one should be

```
alter table yotpo_order_status_history add index (order_id, store_id, created_at desc, id desc);
```

By default, the value is ordered asc, so for the first one, the database engine can't determine the right rowid without scanning all the `id` values.

Comment: note, full recognition and implementation of `desc` indexes comes with [10.8+](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13756). Note the primary key (assumed to be `id`) is already at the end of every secondary index (always ascending). So perhaps a `created_at` (on default `asc`) is all that's needed at the end. With both of them ascending, a reverse search of an index is possible.

Comment: agreed, if `id` is the primary key, then an index on `(order_id, store_id, created_at)` will be the best option.

Comment: look at [explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/) `key_len` to determine how much of an index is used.

Answer (score 1):

Only once.

1. The `=` tests: `order_id, store_id`, in any order
2. The `ORDER BY` `created_at, id`, in the given order

(If you add non-`=` tests or `GROUP BY` or mix `ASC` and `DESC`, etc. the above rules are inadequate!)

(I cannot explain the duplication of `main_table`.`id`)

This tells you how to construct that index:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

(I don't remember ever hearing of repeating columns in the index.  Based on how an indexes works, it should never be necessary.)